# On $a^{2t}+b^{2t}=1\bmod n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

For every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ is there an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that at every $n\in\Bbb N_{>n_{0}}$ we can have coprime solutions $a,b$ (over $\Bbb Z$) such that $n^{\frac1{2t}+\epsilon}<a,b<2n^{\frac1{2t}+\epsilon}$ holds for $ a^{2t}+b^{2t}=1\bmod n$ provided $1\le t\le\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$ holds and is there an effective efficient algorithm under reasonable hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is prime this is quite likely to be true but is beyond reach of current techniques (for $t>1$) as we can only estimate the number of points with coordinates in an interval of size $\sqrt n$.

If $n$ has many prime factors, I think this is unlikely. As soon as $n$ has $r$, say, prime factors of roughly equal size $m = n^{1/(2t)+\epsilon}$, the interval given has only one representative of each residue class modulo such a prime. If $p$ is one of those primes, the number of pairs of residue classes $\pmod p$ satisfying $a^{2t} + b^{2t} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ is roughly $p$ (Weil bound), so the chances that a random pair $a,b$ with $m < a,b < 2m$ satisfies the congruence modulo $p$ is about $1/m$ but you have $r$ conditions so the probability is $1/m^r$ (assuming independence) but you only have $m^2$ pairs, so unlikely if $r>2$. How big is $r$? We have $m^r$ about $n$ so $r(1/(2t)+\epsilon)$ is about $1$, so $r>2$ as soon as $\epsilon < 1/2 - 1/(2t)$. I guess we need $t>1$ for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Also I am looking for only $t=o(\log p)$.

Comment: How about if $n=p^r$ where $p$ is prim?

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Also $(1)$ I am looking for only
$t=o(\log p)$, $(2)$ could you explain why do you think it is likely to be true if $n$ is prime (is there a reasonable algorithm to find under any assumptions?) and $(3)$ what if $n=p^r$ where $p$ is prime?

Comment: @AJ. I was thinking of $t$ as fixed, I don't know if it will change with varying  $t$. I wasn't thinking of algorithms either. You could try plugging in $a$ and solving for $b$. I don't know what happens for prime powers either. Maybe you should think more carefully about what is it that you need.

Comment: @FelipVoloch I will try direct solving (do you recommend a basic reference for these type of problems?). Yes I want to know if for every $t$ from $1$ to $c\cdot\big(\frac{(\log n)^\alpha}{(\log\log n)}\big)$ for some fixed $c>0$ and fixed $\alpha\in(0,1]$ we can have what we want (I think achieving at $\alpha=1$ is not possible and that is why the little $o$ notation).